# Iterating through the numpy array rows

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, contrast

I am trying to take each row of this contrast matrix, perform the operation defined in the denominator variable, add them up, and then divide by the number of rows. When I try to do something like this, I get an "invalid syntax error" (using python 3). This question is from the fMRI univariate analysis context. The X is predefined, you can ignore it. I am just trying to do a dot product with matrices in the denominator variable.

```
X = simulate_two_predictors(N=350, shift=30, TR=2)

contrast_matrix = np.array([

[0, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 1],
[0, 1, -1]

])

for i in range(contrast_matrix.shape[0]):
     denominator = (contrast_matrix[i,:] @ inv(X.T @ X) @ 
     (contrast_matrix[i,:].T))
     return contrast_matrix.size / denominator
```

Can you help me with it? I am quite new.

Comment: You do not have an indent for  `denominator = `. It can be the source of error. Also, you probably should use `contrast_matrix[i, :]` instead `[i:]`. Also, brackets in `denominator =`  do not match.

Comment: Did the comments. now it says 'return' outside function...

Comment: Because you do not define a function to return from. Write `print` instead of `return`.

Comment: Ah I MEANT PRINT OVER THERE! THANKS!

Comment: You may want to close this thread if your issue has been solved.

Comment: will close once I get an answer to my question on waheed rahman's solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I do not know how the output of X simulate_two_predictors look like, I have made a few assumptions.

Correct me if I'm wrong, the return keyword is only valid given that you are returning from a function.

```
import numpy as np

contrast_matrix = np.array([[0, 1, 0],
                            [0, 0, 1],
                            [0, 1, -1]])

X = simulate_two_predictors(N=350, shift=30, TR=2)

for i in range(contrast_matrix.shape[0]):

    # do something here
    denominator = (contrast_matrix[i,:]) @ (np.linalg.inv(X.T @ X) @ (contrast_matrix[i,:].T))

    # reassign value
    contrast_matrix[i,:] = (contrast_matrix.size / denominator)


print(contrast_matrix)
```

Comment: Yes you are right, I accidentally wrote return instead of print. And your suggestion worked. Thanks a lot! Can I ask what exactly np.linalg does over there?

Comment: The np.linalg.inv, calculates the inverse of the matrix, I assumed you were trying to calculate the inverse matrix, hence the function. I thought you might find this link useful, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_inv.htm

Comment: Ah i see, but only inv before the paranthesis does the same thing? :) But will check it out!